# Unity Simple Property Drawer or Popup to display custom object-array scriptable object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm still quite new to unity and c# and trying to replicate a seemingly simple custom editor and property drawer for data i'm preparing  via scriptable object. In this case a class to use multiple tags on a gameObject, to identify what is what quickly when lots of them are detected by a sensor.
I'm on that since way too long and questioning my sanity because it can't be that hard. I'm just lacking some rather basic knowledge/understanding, i think. The whole concept around SerializedProperty and the handling of it is very unintuitive for me.

Found this handy code-snippet here to create LayerMasks containing multiple layers:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(SingleUnityLayer))]
public class SingleUnityLayerPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect _position, SerializedProperty _property, GUIContent _label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(_position, GUIContent.none, _property);
        SerializedProperty layerIndex = _property.FindPropertyRelative("m_LayerIndex");
        _position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(_position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), _label);
        if (layerIndex != null)
        {
            layerIndex.intValue = EditorGUI.LayerField(_position, layerIndex.intValue);
        }
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

which works off this class

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class SingleUnityLayer {
    [SerializeField]
    private int m_LayerIndex = 0;
    private string m_LayerName = "";

    public int LayerIndex {
        get { return m_LayerIndex; }
    }

    public string LayerName {
        get { return m_LayerName; }
    }

    public void Set(int _layerIndex) {
        if(_layerIndex > 0 && _layerIndex < 32) {
            m_LayerIndex = _layerIndex;
            m_LayerName = LayerMask.LayerToName(m_LayerIndex);
        }
    }

    public int Mask {
        get { return 1 << m_LayerIndex; }
    }
}
```

and creates this result, which is great:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1NKK.png)

**Now:**
I want to have the same thing, showing an array of a custom tags scriptable object class or even a simple string[] if necessary but can't get it to work.
The property field for the drawer would be something like `public Tag[] tags;` where the Tag class simply contains a public name property for the moment.

I don't even have the code of my many attempts because it got messy and i kinda gave up and i found some solutions online which i didnt' even try because they seemed way to complex to be necessary for that simple task.

Can someone please push me in the right direction. A little more than "read up on custom editors" would be amazing ;)

Thanks

(not really the topic here but if someone can tell me a better(cheap) way to identify colliders detected with an overlapcircle than with tags, please do tell ;)

(hope the code-blocks and stuff work out..first post)

**Edit:**
After helpful input from @derHugo who understood better what i want than myself, i came up with this simple solution:

```html
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(SingleUnityTag))]
public class SingleUnityTagPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer {
    //string selectedTag = "";
    public override void OnGUI(Rect _position, SerializedProperty _property, GUIContent _label) {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(_position, GUIContent.none, _property);
        SerializedProperty tagIndex = _property.FindPropertyRelative("m_TagIndex");
        SerializedProperty tagName = _property.FindPropertyRelative("m_TagName");
        _position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(_position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), _label);
        if(tagIndex != null) {
            tagName.stringValue = EditorGUI.TagField(_position, tagName.stringValue);
        }
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Found this handy code-snippet here to create LayerMasks containing multiple layers` actually it is kind of the other way round .. by default `LayerMask` is an enum flag which allows multiple values and this drawer allows only a single one to be selected.... What speaks against Unity's default drawer for a list/array of ScriptableObject ?

Comment: `a better(cheap) way to identify colliders detected with an overlapcircle than with tags` would be to use a dedicated layer instead and use the `LayerMask` parameter of the `OverlapCircle` so you only hit the according layers in the first place ...

Comment: thanks @derHugo : So, for a simple example if i would have different enemies, they shouldn't all be on the same layer but on different ones depending on their type?
I assumed it would be better to keep that organized and split up categorization to another level, e.g. tags or something similar.

Comment: would something speak against simply having a [`TagField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.TagField.html) then? I don't really understand what you need your `ScriptableObject` for

Comment: omg, thank you. My brain must really be empty by now. I didn't know it existed but of course it does, if the LayerField exists. So i should be able to really copy the solution for the layers almost exactly -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly now what you actually want is not a `ScriptableObject` at all but rather have a custom tag selection dropdown.

Unfortunately there isn't something built-in for this but you can create one using [`EditorGUI.TagField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.TagField.html) like e.g.

```
    using System;
    using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    using System.Linq;
    using UnityEditor;
#endif

    public class TagAttribute : PropertyAttribute
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(TagAttribute))]
        private class TagAttributeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
        {
            public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
            {
                return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
            }

            public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
            {
                EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

                if (property.propertyType != SerializedPropertyType.String)
                {
                    EditorGUI.HelpBox(position, $"{nameof(TagAttribute)} can only be used for strings!", MessageType.Error);
                    return;
                }

                if (!UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.tags.Contains(property.stringValue))
                {
                    property.stringValue = "";
                }

                var color = GUI.color;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property.stringValue))
                {
                    GUI.color = Color.red;
                }

                property.stringValue = EditorGUI.TagField(position, label, property.stringValue);
                GUI.color = color;

                EditorGUI.EndProperty();
            }
        }
#endif
    }
```

so in your components you can now simply have a

```
[Tag] public string tag;
```

or

```
[Tag] public string[] tags;
```

Comment: Man, thanks a Ton. And even Code for it. I just came back here to mark your first answer as sufficient. Just wrote the code myself. just adapted the Layer Version.

Yes, you're right. I just wanted a custom tag-selection and thought i have to go through the lengths of creating my own tag class and so on.. But your hint was fine.
I'll go through your code aswell and see if i can improve on my solution but it seems i already got it working

Comment: No idea how i can mark this topic as solved or mark your answer as solution, honestly -_-

Comment: I tested your code and it's perfect. Should be the go-to solution! Thanks man. Someone tell me how to flag solutions, please. This is closed :)